# Implementing IConsumerTokenManager for dotnetopenauth

Tags: oauth, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I'm implementing OAuth for a number of providers using dotnetopenauth, which I've found to be very good so far.

I understand I need to implement IConsumerTokenManager to store the tokens and secrets in my database, which makes perfect sense. All good so far.

I'm slightly confused about two things though:

1. The microsoft OAuthWebSecurity class provides methods for registering clients for facebook and linkedin etc, but none of the constructor overloads accept IConsumerTokenManager - does this mean they are using the InMemoryTokenManager under the hood, and if so does this mean I'll have to do custom implementations anyway in order to use my token manager?
2. I've implemented a custom OAuth2Client (DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.OAuth2Client) for google, and there is no overload in the constructor for the OAuth2Client base class which accepts an InMemoryTokenManager - is this class required for OAuth2 is or is the token management handled differently?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IConsumerTokenManager` only applies to OAuth 1.0, but Facebook and Google use OAuth 2.0, so your clients don't need to implement this interface.